# Not getting the message from controller to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to show a message in the view from controller

in my controller:

```
if(json_decode($store) === "Error Code 4G5J3F"){
                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Error!');
            }
```

in my view:

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('message') }}
</div>
@endif
```

and it will return back but won't show the message. why is that happening?

Comment: perhaps your sessions aren't working correctly or there are multiple redirects happening

Comment: then how can i overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change from `session()->has('message')` into `Session::has('message)`

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ Session::get('message') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Hopefully this will help

Comment: its the same thing ... they both are shortcuts to the same underlying session store instance

Comment: same problem, nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Error!');
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32450405)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code with flashing message to the session and reading it in the view.

You could double-check if the `(json_decode($store) === "Error Code 4G5J3F")` condition returns `true`.

Comment: it is true, is it because i'm using API route?